# How to append the GUID from a record within Microsoft CRM Online to a email workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I've built a custom web application (asp.net c#) that interfaces with the CRM SDK successfully, however I want to have a workflow within Microsoft CRM Online that generates an email to a customer with a custom URL + GUID of there record

Dear Name,

Please click here HREF = (http://example.com/confirm.aspx?id=GUID) to confirm your booking.

Does anyone know how this is achievable in Microsoft CRM Online?

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

you need to rely on the property `PrimaryEntityId` of `IWorkflowContext` object:

```
IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
Guid recordId = context.PrimaryEntityId;
```

but to use the value inside the workflow you need to create a Custom Workflow Activity. Follow this link, it provides the code you need:

http://dynamicslollipops.blogspot.com/2011/10/mscrm-2011-workflow-assembly-get.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a new workflow and add a step "Send Email"

Comment: I wished it was that simple. You cannot just extracted the GUID part as its not a separate field to chose from within a workflow.